# Finding the value of $ k $.

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations

Find all real value of $ k $ such that the system of equation
\begin{align}
a^2 + ab &= kc^2 \\
b^2 + bc &= ka^2 \\
c^2 + ca &= kb^2
\end{align}
have positive real number solution for $ a $, $ b $, and $ c $.

I have already found the value of $ k $. Here is my solution.
Adding all of the equation, we found that
$$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ab + bc + ca = k\left(a^2 + b^2 + c^2\right) $$
or
$$ k - 1 = \frac{ab + bc + ca}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}. $$
Since $ ab + bc + ca \leq a^2 + b^2 + c^2 $ for $ a, b, c \in \mathbb{R^{+}} $,
$$ k - 1 \leq \frac{ab + bc + ca}{ab + bc + ca} = 1 \iff k \leq 2. $$
My question is, is my solution is wrong? Or did I missed something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have proved that $k \le 2$ is necessary, but have not shown it is sufficient.

If $k=-1$, we have three equations like $a^2+ab=-c^2$.  This cannot be satisfied with $a,b,c$ positive.  This applies for any $k \le 0$.

Now it remains to show that there is a solution for any $k$ with $0 \lt k \le 2$

As the equations are homogeneous, for any solution $(a,b,c)$ you have $(da,db,dc)$ is also a solution, so you can choose $d=\frac 1a$ or (equivalently) set $a=1$.  That reduces you to two unknowns and gives you an easy substitution.

Comment: Oh, I don't realized that there are no positive real solution for $ k \leq 0 $. But I think, there is no solution too for $ k \ne 2 $.